A fairy tale based series
I once saw this series set in modern time. There was this normal girl who worked in a restaurant and then suddenly fairy tale characters started to show up, her father was a plumber and I remember he got a wish granted in which all the family members of his enemy (the person who owned their rented house) started serving him. Then there was this bad wolf who was a guy and stole the girl to the fairy tale land and there they had a lot of adventures and in every one the girl experienced one character like Snow White or Rapunzel.
Her mother had mental issues and had tried to drown her in a tub when she was young and then the mother ran off into the evil queen and took her place; at the end the evil queen dies and the girl and the wolf get married.
Do you know what is it?

Hi and welcome to M&TV. Do you remember the year? The country\language?

It is a fantasy miniseries called The 10th Kingdom (2000)

A father and daughter are caught in a parallel universe where the great queens Snow White, Cinderella, and Little Red Riding Hood have had their kingdoms fragmented by warring trolls, giants and goblins




Wikipedia



